# I load a table from a db into a store. I want to send a row from the store back to the db so I can access it in a shopping cart. How do I do this?

Tags: angular

I need to send data from a store to a shopping cart

The database is mysql, I use express to communicate with the database. 
A button loads alongside each table row to add to cart, I need these to send the data back to the cart table in my database.

I've looked into services to try and do this but I am confused by these.

TypeScript file for the store

```js
export class StoreComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private Http: HttpClient, private Auth : AuthService) { }
  list: any;
  loggedIn = false;
  columns = [ 'scriptName','category', 'uploadDate', 'category', 'rating' ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedIn = this.Auth.loggedIn
    let store = this.Http.get('http://localhost:3000/store');
    store.subscribe((response) => {

      this.list=response;
      console.log(response)
    });
  }
```

html for the store

```html
<table>
      <tr *ngFor="let li of list">
        <td>
          Name: {{li.scriptName}}<br>
          Description: {{li.description}}<br>
          Category: {{li.category}}<br>
        </td>

        <td><button type="button" value="{{li.storeID}}">Add to Cart</button></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

java script for the sql

```
app.get('/store', (req,res) => {
    let sql = 'Select * from store'
    let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

I want the add to cart button to send that row to the cart table in the database

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have different ways of determining which cart belongs to who on your carts table. I'm also assuming that your data structure is relational. Then why not store the items in the person's cart but just taking the `id` of the item from the client side and passing it to your server to store against that cart...

```
<table>
      <tr *ngFor="let li of list">
        <td>
          Name: {{li.scriptName}}<br>
          Description: {{li.description}}<br>
          Category: {{li.category}}<br>
        </td>

        <td><button type="button" (click)="addToCart(li.storeId)" value="{{li.storeID}}">Add to Cart</button></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

On your component:

```
export class StoreComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private Http: HttpClient, private Auth : AuthService) { }
  list: any;
  loggedIn = false;
  columns = [ 'scriptName','category', 'uploadDate', 'category', 'rating' ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedIn = this.Auth.loggedIn
    let store = this.Http.get('http://localhost:3000/store');
    store.subscribe((response) => {

      this.list=response;
      console.log(response)
    });
  }

  addToCart(id) {
     let store = this.Http.post('http://localhost:3000/store', { cartId: cid, itemId: id });

  // Add your logic here to post that your cart...Above is just an example
  // Suggestion is to remove the http logic over to a service.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what `@ngrx/effects` is for: https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

> Effects are where you handle tasks such as fetching data, long-running tasks that produce multiple events, and other external interactions where your components don't need explicit knowledge of these interactions.

Take a look at the manual. You can use `@ngrx/effects` to make the API call to your backend every time you perform the 'addToCart' action (assuming the cart is also part of your Store)